# A-FRAME setTimeout in setTimout using tick function

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm using a setTimeout to change the visibility of the body to "hidden" after 2sec, and i want to put it back to visible 2 seconds later but i'm in a tick function so it's called like 10 times per seconds and it doesn't do what i expect :

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent("listener", {
    tick: function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";
            },2000) 
        },2000)
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <a-scene>
          <a-plane position="0 0 0" width="14" height="14"></a-plane>
        </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Should it say `AFRAME` instead of `AFAME` in the code sample?

Comment: Right, just a little mistake when i wrote it, the problem doesn't come from that

Comment: Have you read through https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/best-practices.md#tick-handlers ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're calling the setTimout functions inside AFRAME's **tick** handler - which in turn means it will be called over and over again every frame.

If you want something to happen just once, the **init** handler is the correct place.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("listener", {
    init: function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";
            },2000) 
        },2000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you i didn't know about that, but i'm using a tick handler to get the user's position, to create some event like when the user is between some coordinate, it triggers an event, but if i do this in init handler, the position of user is always x: 0, y: 0, z:0, what can i do ?

Comment: Hm, you could probably initialize a variable like `isBetweenCoordinates=false` inside the init handler. In your tick handler, beside checking for the proper coordinates, you should check if this variable is still false and if it is, do the desired action and also set the variable to true. This will make sure it just executes once.

Answer (score 0):

Since tick runs 90 times per second. Try the following if you want to keep using it.

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const hide = () => {
   if(body.style.visibility !== "hidden") {body.style.visibility = "hidden";}}
const show = () => {
   if(body.style.visibility !== "visible") {document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";}}
const letsFlick = (start, now) => {
  if(!start) { start = new Date(); }
  now = new Date();
  if(now - start >= 2000) {
    hide();
    if(now - start >= 4000) {
      show();
      start = new Date();
    }
  }
}
let start; 
let now;
AFRAME.registerComponent("listener", {
    tick: function() {
      letsFlick(start, now);
    }
}
```

You can probably tell the loop will be a great waste of runtime resources and you'd probably want to use init if you just want to flick once as per @obscure's answer.